# How to redirect with .htaccess when files are going name/?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My title is confusing, I know. So I'll try to explain thorougly.

At the moment, I have a .htaccess file that does this:

```
   RewriteRule ^Logga-in login.php [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^Skapa-Ett-Konto create.php [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^Logga-ut logout.php [NC,L]
   RewriteRule ^Hem index.php [NC,L]
```

So if I click on "index.php" it will say "Hem" in the address bar. But, if I write something like "server/Hemaaujsndua" or "server/Hem/aidnad" it doesn't redirect, and I will stay on the same site. I haven't been working with htaccess, but I saw a tutorial recently. I did exactly as he did, but my turns like this.

I appreciate any answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question...

If you try to rewrite when words are used:

(/server/Hemaaujsndua -> index.php)

```
RewriteRule Logga-in /login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule Skapa-Ett-Konto /create.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule Logga-ut /logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule Hem /index.php [NC,L]
```

OR only when the URL is identical:

(/Hem -> index.php)

```
RewriteRule ^Logga-in$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Skapa-Ett-Konto$ create.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Logga-ut$ logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Hem$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Chang your last rule

```
   RewriteRule ^Hem index.php [NC,L]
```

with

```
   RewriteRule ^.*Hem index.php [NC,L]
```

Regex ".*" matchs any characters zero or more time.

Comment: Yes, but with regex, `^.*Hem` is the same as `Hem`. No need to add `any characters from start`, It's `Hem` somewhere.